# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (User and Comment models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #6):

3:   <div class="post-author">
4:     <div class="post-author-info">
5:       <span class="post-author-name">
6:         <strong><%= link_to comment.user.email, comment.user %></strong>
7:       </span>
8: 
9:       <span class="post-date secondary">
```

comments.rb:

```
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    comment_attr = params[:comment].merge :user_id => current_user.id
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_attr)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

post.rb:

```
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

user.rb:

```
 has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

comment.rb:

```
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

schema.rb:

```
 create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end
```

I'm not sure what's the problem. Everything seems fine in the files above.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

posts/show.html.erb:

```
<div id="post-<%= @post.id %>" class="post-single">
  <h3 class="post-title"><%= @post.title %></h3>

  <span class="post-author-name">
    <strong><%= link_to @post.user.email, @post.user %></strong>
  </span>

  <span class="post-content">
    <%= @post.content %>
  </span>

  <div class="comments">
    <h4 class="comments-count"><%= pluralize(@post.comments_count, "Comment") %></h4>

    <%= render @comments %>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

comments/_comment.html.erb:

```
<div id="comment-<%= comment.id %>" class="comment">

  <div class="post-author">
    <div class="post-author-info">
      <span class="post-author-name">
        <strong><%= link_to comment.user.email, comment.user %></strong>
      </span>

      <span class="post-date secondary">
        <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
      </span>
    </div>

    <span class="post-author-control">
      <% unless current_user == nil %>
        <% if current_user.id == comment.user_id %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="comment-body">
    <p><%= comment.content %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

posts.rb:

```
  def show

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comment = @post.comments.build
  end
```

comments/_form.html.erb:

Add a comment:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the following line in your controller creates a comment object that is related to a post, but not to user and thus causes the error in your partial:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build
```

To get rid of the error you should either change the line above to:

```
@comment = Comment.new
```

or remove that line from your controller and change your comment form to:

```
<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do the `DELETE FROM comments WHERE user_id IS NULL` from the rails console?

Comment: @Thanks, but I think there are no NULL user_ids:  `SQL (90.6ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE (user_id IS NULL)
 => 0 ` I did the command and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then it must be the second scenario where you have a `user_id` in your comments table, but the `id` does not exist in the users table.

Comment: but I created a new user and created a new post. And as soon as I'm redirected to the post, the error appears.

Comment: So you don't have any comments yet? Where is `comment` coming from? Could you show that code? This happens in `posts#show`?

Comment: OK, see my EDIT (I never deleted any user).

Comment: strange when I request for the user email on the console it works:` 1.9.3-p0 :005 > comment.user.email
 => "weedcl@hotmail.com" 
1.9.3-p0 :006 > ` and I get this if I remove that line: "can't convert nil into an exact number." So comment.created_at is nill, strange.

Comment: Well you don't have a saved comment. That seems to be the problem. What happens if you remove `@comment = @post.comments.build` from your controller?

Comment: I get this: `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`
I think the comment is saved because if I remove comment.user.email and comment.created_at the comment.content shows up.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you are trying to do. You said: "but I created a new user and created a new post. And as soon as I'm redirected to the post, the error appears." How can you create a comment before a post??

Comment: I mean, I created a new user, then a new post, and then a comment for the post. It seems like only comment.content works. Strange.

Comment: Strange, though I created only one comment I see two divs: one with id `comment-` and another with id `comment-1`

Comment: That's probably because of `@comment = @post.comments.build`. What does the form for creating a comment look like? I think you should get rid of the line above and in the comment form do `<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>`.

Comment: OK, added `_form` see my EDIT (by the way, thanks for being so patient).

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working. The reason is that `@comment = @post.comments.build` creates a new comment object that is not saved and not related to a user, but it *is* related to a post, so it gets picked up by the partial where it causes errors. By simply using `Comment.new` in the form, you prevent this.

Comment: Alternatively you could keep the form like it was and change the line in your controller to: `@comment = Comment.new`. I updated my answer to show the solution to your problem.